# boto3: Create a instance with an instanceprofile/ IAM Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I want to write a script that starts servers for me and does the setup. It should:

- Create two S3-Buckets and set its CORS (solved)
- Create a ec2 server based on an image
- give this server access to that bucket

What I have found so far is how to create the bucket and how to create the instance itself:

```py
#@see http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#ec2

aws = boto3.Session(profile_name="myProfile")

s3 = aws.resource('s3', region_name='my-region-1')
bucket = s3.create_bucket(
    Bucket='my-cool-bucket', 
    #...
)
#...

ec2 = aws.resource('ec2', region_name='my-region-1')

ec2.create_instances(
     ImageId="my-ami-image-id",
     MinCount=1,  # I want exactly 1 server
     MaxCount=1,
     KeyName='my-ssh-key',
     SecurityGroupIds=['my-security-group'],
     UserData=myStartupScript, # script that will start when server starts
     InstanceType='t2.nano',
     SubnetId="my-subnet-id",
     DisableApiTermination=True,
     PrivateIpAddress='10.0.0.1',
     #...
)
```

but how do I now create the Role for that server and give that role access to the bucket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the way to create the InstanceProfile:

https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.ServiceResource.create_instance_profile

```
instance_profile = iam.create_instance_profile(
    InstanceProfileName='string',
    Path='string'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to:

- Create an [InstanceProfile](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.InstanceProfile)
- **Associate a Role** to the Instance Profile
- Launch the instance(s) with the `IamInstanceProfile` parameter

Comment: but how do I create the InstanceProfile? I cannot find any `create` method in the documentation

Comment: does `iam.InstanceProfile('name')` create a new InstanceProfile? If yes, very bad docs, if not, I have not found what you ment.

Comment: That is my assumption, too.

Comment: Thanks for your support, but that seems not to solve the problem. I have found that the methods for creating the Objects are usually in the ServiceResource Class. See my answer for detail.

Answer (score 1):

Create a role named **Test-emr-instance-role**, then you can use this code to create an instance profile and attach a role to the instance profile.

```
session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='myProfile') 
iam = session.client('iam')

instance_profile = iam.create_instance_profile (
    InstanceProfileName ='Test-emr-instance-profile' 
)

response = iam.add_role_to_instance_profile (
    InstanceProfileName = 'Test-emr-instance-profile',
    RoleName            = 'Test-emr-instance-role' 
)
```